# LINQPad EF Core no database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linqpad

I'm using LINQPad 6 (Premium Edition).

I have created a connection to my custom assembly via the Entity Framework Core (2.x, 3.x, 5.x) driver. I chose to instantiate the DbContext via a constructor that accepts a string.
[image]

If I create a new query off of this connection using "C# Expression" it works fine.
[image: C# Expression]

```
Stuff.Take(100)
```

But if I choose "C# Statement(s)" with a sample query like below I get an error saying -

> "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext..."

```
var _context = new MyContext();

var dataModel = _context.Stuff.Include(r => r.ParentStuff).ThenInclude(c => c.ChildStuff).FirstOrDefault(x => x.StuffId == 1234);

dataModel.Dump();
```

This error is confusing because I setup the provider when setting up the EF Core connection in LINQPad. If the database provider wasn't configured then I would think it would throw this error for both queries.

Comment: What if you choose your database connection in the `Connection` dropdown, and use `Stuff.Take(100)` in C# statements? Not sure why you need to create a new context. You should be able to use `UserQuery` once the connection is chosen, and the `UserQuery` type should be inherited from your DB context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `new` to create a new `DbContext`, you should [set your `DbContext` class up for the scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#simple-dbcontext-initialization-with-new).

Creating connection using EF Core driver in LinqPad does not automatically send connection string to instances of your `DbContext` created by `new`.

So you have two options:

- Pass connection string using the constructor overload which takes a string in your C# statements when creating the `DbContext`, e.g. `new MyContext(connStr)`
- Select the connection with EF Core driver in the `Connection` dropdown, and use `this` to access properties in your `DbContext`.

Comment: This worked! - I'd have never have thought to use "var _db=this" to instantiate my db context.